# Undefined function 'time' for input arguments of type 'double'. How do i find a function that others didn't seem to have defined in their code?

Tags: matlab, function, undefined

I was calling the **mpretrack** function written by [Kilfoil's Lab](http://people.umass.edu/kilfoil/downloads.html), and it crashed, saying:

```
Undefined function 'time' for input arguments of type 'double'.
Error in mpretrack (line 112)
```

I opened `mpretrack.m` and went to line 112:

```
MT(d+1:a+d, 7)=time(x);
```

How could I find the definition of `time`? They didn't seem to give a `time.m` file and I don't think they were trying to use the Matlab function `time()` which measures CPU time.

I will paste a few more context lines of `mpretrack.m` of line 112

```
a = length(M(:,1));

MT(d+1:a+d, 1:5)=M(1:a,1:5);
MT(d+1:a+d, 6)=x;
MT(d+1:a+d, 7)=time(x);
d = length(MT(:,1));
disp([num2str(a) ' features kept.'])
```

Comment: Most probably it's supposed to be just a variable (not a function) containing the time of some event(?), You could search for `time` or similar in the whole file and see where it could be originated.

Comment: My first day in Stackoverflow. OMG. It's really quick in response. I just figured it's a varable and came back to delete the question. But, lol. Thanks man!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pm89 already suspected, `time` in this case is a variable. Type:

```
> help mpretrack
```

in your command window. Amongst other information, it will say:

> Also, the program looks for the files "fov#*times.mat" for the "time"
>     variable and the images files "fov#\fov#*####.tif" from the basepath.

If you don't have the specified `.mat` file, the variable `time` is unknown, which causes the error you see.

Comment: Yes I just realized it is. I'm sorry that I can't vote yet. But thanks very much for your reply.

Comment: @SuicideBunny you can still accept the answer by clicking the checkmark (✓) next to the voting buttons